# can I automate integrating packages/frameworks in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

For implementing our unity3d project into iOS, we need to manually select/tune a long list of tweaks in xcode build menu every time we build the project to test it (mainly to use appodeal framework).

Is there an easy way this task can be automated?
for example, in android builds, I reuse the same manifest file for the project and everything works just fine. Is there a similar way for xcode?

Comment: can I automate integrating packages/frameworks and set defaults using xcodebuild?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "tweaks in xcode build menu" means?

Comment: Sure, have a look at this:
http://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=2&full=1&platform=2
our real problem is step 5.1.3... every time we need to search and add all these frameworks manually :-(

Comment: You should only have to do that once.  The project file remembers which libraries to link from one build to the next.

Comment: We are exporting the project from unity every time... may be that's why it doesn't remember our preferences

Answer (score 1):

This is Andrew from Appodeal support. In the last release of Unity plugin (0.4.9) we have post build function which can help to resolve this issue.

You can download it here: [Download_link](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/appodeal-crossplatform/appodeal-unity/1.13.1_0.4.9/AppodealUnity.unitypackage)